# *10 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream with uwsgi

Tags: django, database, postgresql, nginx, uwsgi

I currently have a server setup with `nginx` and `uwsgi` with `django`
This error doesn't happen until I try to change my `rds instance`

my fully error message is 
`*10 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, request: "GET /load/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/tmp/load.sock", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/"`

I was using aws rds (`postgres`) which works perfectly fine.  The only change I made is changing from regular `postgres` service to `aurora postgres` I didn't upgrade the db, from regular to aurora.  I created a new `aurora postgres`.  I got everything setup...changed host and everything in my `django db setting`.  `runserver` locally works fine.  It does connect to db with read and write.  Works perfectly.  But when I deploy to server, open up my domain.  Anything ui related looks fine but db related, NO.  Took awhile then of course the 504 gateway timeout.  I went to checkout the `nginx error log`.  That's the error message I found.  Googled, tried a few settings other `stackoverflow` posts suggested such as adding`single-interpreter = true` into `uwsgi.ini` file.  No luck.

Can someone please give me an idea where I should look into for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try going to your rds instance, check its' security group setting.  Happened to me once, too me a while to find out that the security group setting is the problem.  I didn't recall setting up the security group but it restricted with local IP